# mapping an apigee pre flow policy to validate from map values

Tags: apigee

Lets say I have an entry in a map I create . How do I create a policy to correlate a param variable that comes in the client request with an entry in the map and if they do not correlate raising an error fault . I know in apigee 3.8 there was a studio where I could modify the connection parameters to make this but I am truly confused on how I could do this in the edge version

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a condition to do this. In the example below 'flow.variable.myvariable' would be a custom variable (you can call it whatever you want). Use the KeyValueMap policy type to get the value out the key value store and populate it in the custom variable that you use to do the comparison.

```
<Flow>
 <Condition>request.queryparam.myparam != flow.variable.myvariable</Condition>
  <Request>
   <Step>
    <Name>ReturnAnErrorUsingAssignMessagePolicy</Name>
   </Step>
  </Request>
</Flow>
```

There are a couple of moving parts here. If you provide a bit more detail on the specifics of your implementation, we can get you more detailed info. For example, what "connection parameters" are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

Maps in Apigee Edge are can be used are a little different in use then the Maps that where available in Apigee 3.8.  In 3.8 you would use a Service Callout to retrieve your data something like this http://{somehostname}/map/entry/attributes?map_name=map1&key=key1 where key1 is the key you where referencing, in Apigee Edge we facilitate this functionality by making available a policy that retrieves that information so that you don't have to worry about managing the service callouts needed to add and retrieve data.

The policy you use for any Map data operation is called KeyValueMapOperations

```
<KeyValueMapOperations async="false" continueOnError="false" enabled="true" name="getDataFromKVM">
<DisplayName>GetDataFromKVM</DisplayName>
<Get assignTo="kvmData" index="1">
    <Key>
        <Parameter ref="request.queryparam.key"></Parameter>
    </Key>
</Get>
<Scope>environment</Scope>
```

If you want to check to see if the key exists you can have a condition on the referenced variable in your API flow, you also do this kind of checking on the response variable after this policy runs in your flow.

For more information on how key value maps work in Apigee edge refer too

http://apigee.com/docs/api-services/content/persist-data-using-keyvaluemap